# How to parse GraphSON data from Neptune as a list of dictionaries?

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

If you make a signed request using the code provided by AWS here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/iam-auth-connecting-python.html

Then if you do a query like this from a python script:

```
make_signed_request(query="g.V().limit(10).valueMap(true).toList()")
```

It outputs an ugly unusable thing like this:

```
{
    "requestId": "bf942e84-ff49-42c7-a65c-ef43f45g5h63",
    "status": {
        "message": "",
        "code": 200,
        "attributes": {
            "@type": "g:Map",
            "@value": []
        }
    },
    "result": {
        "data": {
            "@type": "g:List",
            "@value": [
                {
                    "@type": "g:Map",
                    "@value": [
                        "names",
                        {
                            "@type": "g:List",
                            "@value": ["David Bowie"]
                        }
                       ..., etc.
```

Whereas if I run the same query on a notebook, like this:

```
%%gremlin --store-to foo

g.V().limit(10).valueMap(true).toList()
```

Then `foo` is a nicely formatted list of dictionaries, like this:

```
[
    {'names': ['David Bowie'], 'dob': [08-01-1947]},
    {'names': ['Michael Jackson'], 'dob': [29-08-1958]},
]
```

How do I get the maked_signed_request function to return data in the same way that the notebook does?

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is the default HTTP response format that you can expect to see from any "Gremlin Server compatible" TinkerPop endpoint. Under the covers, the graph-notebook notebooks are using the Gremlin Python client and sending the request over a web socket. The Gremlin Python client nicely de-serializes that result for you. You essentially have two options when calling the Neptune Gremlin endpoint.

1. Use a specific Gremlin client for your preferred programming language (if one exists).
2. Call the HTTP endpoint and post process the GraphSON result. Rather than write your own you can most likely repurpose the serializers from one of the clients. If possible I would use option 1.